# Libtorch: How to load an ONNX-model?

Tags: c++, pytorch, onnx, libtorch

I need to load and run an ONNX-model in a C++ environment using Libtorch on Windows 10 (Visual Studio 2015, v140). Searching the web, there seem to be almost exclusivly instructions for how to do it in Python. Is there a well documented way/does anyone know how to this in C++?

Answer (score -2):

Here's two C++ based resources that might be relevant:

1. The [ONNX Runtime C++ API](https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/onnxruntime/core/session/inference_session.h) enables inference and loading ONNX models with C++.
2. [Windows ML C++ APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-started-desktop) can be leveraged to load ONNX models in C++ Windows desktop applications.

Comment: This answer might be better as a comment, since it doesn't fully answer the question. If the combination of these resources are sufficient to answer the question, then the answer should be expanded to represent that.